Manga with a main character that has an intimidation skill that runs in his family
I'm looking to identify this manga about a main character that is born into a family with this intimidation or ability that perceives him as evil when he hasn't done anything. The mc has been misjudged by a maid in the early chapters and tries to change her view about him. Another chapter is where at a party mc helps the kids but some of them are still afraid of him. Another piece of information I have is a girl that originally was to help the hero is now helping the mc now. The intimidation skill is passed down through the family so his father has this skill as well. It's been a bit since I've read it and I said isekai bc a I remember him being transferred here but I can't remember if it was a game or a novel but he was a reborn as a villian

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Sorry, but the "intimidatiion skill" is a common trope in Isekai. Weakest Tamer, Collecting Trash, So I'm a spider, Emperor Skills, etc etc. the list goes on

Voting to reopen because I believe the original complaint was resolved, but can you describe what makes this fantasy or sci fi? Right now it seems like he and his father are both good at intimidating others, but I wouldn't say that's especially fantastical.

@MishaR - OP has tagged it as an Isekai

When did you first read this manga? Also, is this an Isekai manga? I'm asking because you used the [isekai] tag but did not mention it in the question body.

That Is Needed for a Villainous Aristocrat, a.k.a
This Is Needed for a Villainous Aristocrat, Akuyaku Kizoku to shite Hitsuyou na Sore, or 悪役貴族として必要なそれ

A story of a man with evil charisma: A young man who's lived in modern
Japan suddenly realized that he had been reborn in his favorite
fantasy novel, "The Tale of the Rhinana Kingdom". Yet he wasn’t reborn
as the protagonist, but as the famous villain Marquis in the story.
With the fate of being overthrown looming above him, he takes all
action to break free of his determined fate by using his future
knowledge along with the strongest skill "Absolute Evil".


guy is reincarnated as person known to be and intended to be evil
there is a hero character that seeks to bring our protagonist down
there is a slave/maid very faithful to our protag, whom hero wants to free from her evil owner
protag has some magical skill, specific to his family, called "absolute evil" and does intimidate people.


It certainly is on-topic (fantasy) and I must say your description was accurate, so don't worry about downvotes ;-)

It looks like it's only available in English via fan translation. See MAL for more details, including the link to the original.
